# paging and filtering not working when I convert radgrid detailtable to default edit mode

Tags: telerik, radgridview

Hi please any one help me..
  I have a telerik radgrid with one detailtable for each record which displays the subrecords. My requirement is getting only detailtable to default editmode when i expand each record. This task i was able to acheive successfully by writing the edit logic in grid prerender method. The problem is after changing to edit mode any postback events on detail table are not working properly like paging and filtering functinality etc..

What was the extra functionality i need to add. I am using linq to sql datasource for my radgrid.

Comment: if any body intrested i will share my code..please reply me

Comment: Please provide your code.